# How to access Search Bar on tap callback

Tags: swift, uisearchbar

Im building an app and I have a search bar with table view.
But I don't how when users tap the search, go to the data at different View Controller
Someone can help me pls ?
My code almost like that

```
@IBOutlet weak var textSearchBar: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var tableSearchResult: UITableView!

var fruitsArray:[String] = Array()
var searchedArray:[String] = Array()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    
    fruitsArray.append("Apple")
    fruitsArray.append("Orange")
    fruitsArray.append("Litch")
    fruitsArray.append("Pineapple")
    
    for str in fruitsArray {
        searchedArray.append(str)
    }
    tableSearchResult.dataSource = self
    textSearchBar.delegate = self
}

// Mark:- UITableViewDataSource

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return searchedArray.count
}


func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    var cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell")
    
    if cell == nil {
        cell = UITableViewCell(style: .default, reuseIdentifier: "cell")
        
    }
    
    cell?.textLabel?.text = searchedArray [indexPath.row]
    return cell!
}

    // MARK: - UITextFieldDelegate

func textFieldShouldClear(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
    textSearchBar.resignFirstResponder()
    textSearchBar.text = ""
    self.searchedArray.removeAll()
    for str in fruitsArray {
        searchedArray.append(str)
    }
    tableSearchResult.reloadData()
    return true
}
```

Thank you Very Much

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
extension ViewController: UISearchBarDelegate {
    func searchBar(
        _ searchBar: UISearchBar,
        textDidChange searchText: String
    ) {
        // Here instructions for when searchBarText change 
    }
    
    func searchBarCancelButtonClicked(
        _ searchBar: UISearchBar
    ) {
        self.searchBar.endEditing(true)
    }
}
```

Comment: What should i write to instructions?

Comment: For exemple: If you have a TableView who contains fruits, you can make a (function) which reloads the view table with a array that contains only the fruits which begins with the letters entered until arriving at a single fruit. So call this (function) here